# Show usb webcam on top of raspberry webcam

Tags: camera, raspicam

I have a raspberry pi with a raspberrypi cam and a usb webcam.
With raspivid I can display the raspberrypi cam video on screen and with vlc I can didplay the usb webcam.

I need to display the usb webcam on top of the raspberrypi cam feed, but raspivid is always on top.

How can I play the usb webcam feed ontop of the raspberrypi cam feed?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience , for raspivid [option](https://www.raspberrypi.org/app/uploads/2013/07/RaspiCam-Documentation.pdf):

```
--preview, -p Preview window settings <'x,y,w,h'>
```

You can use this for your raspivid window position on the screen. Assume raspivid on the left on your screen, then you can open vlc in a new window and put it on the right of the screen.

If you want a foreground window, you can use OPENCV [highgui](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html) and put the window where you want, you can also use python [picamera](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/recipes1.html).

**EDIT: This solution not work :**
VLC gui can be by default, manipulate by the user and then you can put it on top with a very usefull Linux trick:

right click on the vlc window (in the window header on the side of the window title) and choose Position:

```
Always on top
```

Comment: I tried the vlc always on top option, but it's still under raspivid

Comment: ho, sorry... the best choice is probably to not use rapivid but [picamera python](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/recipes1.html)  lib or opencv (imshow()) for display a new manipulable window.